# socket.io problems. Not able to connect. front end says connection: false and backend doesn't log anything

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, http, socket.io

i am new to socket.io and i can't get it to connect to react app. here is my app.js in node

```
const express = require('express');
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const router = require('./routes/routes');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const db = require('./db/db');

const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', () => {
  console.log('connected');
});

app.use('*', cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
(router);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('listening on port ' + port);
  db.sync({
    // force: true,
    logging: false,
  });
});
```

and my front end code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
import classes from './Chatroom.module.css';

const Chatroom = ({ user, getAllMessages, setGetAllMessages }) => {
  const ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:4000/getallmessages';
  var socket = io(ENDPOINT);

  const messagesEndRef = useRef(null);

  const scrollToBottom = () => {
    messagesEndRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('connect', () => {
      socket.send('hello');
      console.log('connected.');
    });
    console.log(socket);
  }, []);
```

Whenever i look in the console on it shows connected: false and nothing is logging on the backend.

Answer (score 2):

In order to fix the issue i had to add options to my io declaration as follows.

```
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const options = {
  cors: true,
  origins: ['http://127.0.0.1:3000'],
};
const io = require('socket.io')(server, options);
```

127.0.0.1 being home and on client side my server is on 3000 so that's where that comes from. and on the client side you were right i had to remove "getallmessages" route so now it is as follows.

```
onst ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:4000/';
  var socket = io(ENDPOINT);

  const messagesEndRef = useRef(null);

  const scrollToBottom = () => {
    messagesEndRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('connect', () => {
      socket.send('hello');
      console.log('connected.');
    });
    console.log(socket);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

socket.io is bound to the server object so you should listen to the server instead of the app.

- Change  `app.listen` to `server.listen`
- Change  endpoint by removing `getallmessages` if you are not using namespaces